How to open display adapter settings window using a shortcut
I want to open the display properties window using a shortcut. Searched for a .cpl file but there is none.


To directly open the Display Properties dialog,

Right-click on the Windows Desktop.

Select New > Shortcut.

In the box for location, type or paste the following:
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe display.dll,ShowAdapterSettings

or, if you prefer to use system variables,
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe display.dll,ShowAdapterSettings


Add a space and number for a particular display, e.g., for Display 1:
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe display.dll,ShowAdapterSettings 0


Click Next and save the shortcut with appropriate name.

Right-click the new Desktop shortcut and add your choice of Shortcut key.


